# openni_node.launch no longer in openni_camera?

Tags: kinect, openni-camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm not sure if this is a bug or a planned change, but up until not too long ago, I'd swear I was always able to fire up a connection to my Kinect with the command:

```
$ roslaunch openni_camera openni_node.launch
```

Now in the latest Electric RC-1 Debian packages, the file openni_node.launch no longer exists.  Not sure if it disappeared earlier than RC-1.  Has anyone else run into this or am I having a senior moment?

--patrick

**UPDATE**:  Thanks to Mike's answer below, I tried launching from the new location:

```
$ roslaunch openni_launch openni.launch
```

And amid the INFO messages, I get a number of ERROR messages as listed below.  Also, I get a blank image in image_view when I try:

```
$ rosrun image_view image_view image:=/camera/rgb/image_color
```

Here now is the output from openni.launch:

```
[ERROR] [1314123870.086794930]: Tried to advertise a service that is already advertised in this node [/camera/depth_registered/image_rect_raw/compressed/set_parameters]
[ERROR] [1314123870.096387560]: Tried to advertise a service that is already advertised in this node [/camera/depth_registered/image_rect_raw/theora/set_parameters]
[ INFO] [1314123874.255698250]: Number devices connected: 1
[ INFO] [1314123874.256049202]: 1. device on bus 001:20 is a Xbox NUI Camera (2ae) from Microsoft (45e) with serial id 'B00362222624036B'
[ INFO] [1314123874.257676854]: Searching for device with index = 1
[ INFO] [1314123874.334089426]: Opened 'Xbox NUI Camera' on bus 1:20 with serial number 'B00362222624036B'
[ INFO] [1314123874.370155878]: rgb_frame_id = '/camera_rgb_optical_frame' 
[ INFO] [1314123874.370254144]: depth_frame_id = '/camera_depth_optical_frame' 
[ INFO] [1314123874.375764411]: using default calibration URL
[ INFO] [1314123874.375919878]: camera calibration URL: file:///home/patrick/.ros/camera_info/rgb_B00362222624036B.yaml
[ERROR] [1314123874.376112291]: Unable to open camera calibration file [/home/patrick/.ros/camera_info/rgb_B00362222624036B.yaml]
[ WARN] [1314123874.376192120]: Camera calibration file /home/patrick/.ros/camera_info/rgb_B00362222624036B.yaml not found.
[ INFO] [1314123874.378165834]: using default calibration URL
[ INFO] [1314123874.378270805]: camera calibration URL: file:///home/patrick/.ros/camera_info/depth_B00362222624036B.yaml
[ERROR] [1314123874.378358246]: Unable to open camera calibration file [/home/patrick/.ros/camera_info/depth_B00362222624036B.yaml]
[ WARN] [1314123874.378610024]: Camera calibration file /home/patrick/.ros/camera_info/depth_B00362222624036B.yaml not found.
[ WARN] [1314123874.380757992]: Using default parameters for RGB camera calibration.
[ WARN] [1314123874.380868691]: Using default parameters for IR camera calibration.
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10987/openni_node.launch-no-longer-in-openni_camera?/) by [Pi Robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/30/pi-robot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 4046 on 2011-08-23

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Launch files have moved to the "openni_launch" package.

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2011-08-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Pi Robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/30/pi-robot/) on 2011-08-23**:
Got it--thanks!

**Comment by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) on 2011-08-23**:
You'll also have to dynamic reconfigure to turn on depth_registration, as it no longer does so automatically (you can also set a rosparam parameter)

**Comment by [Pi Robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/30/pi-robot/) on 2011-08-23**:
Thanks Fergs,--however, launching the new openni.launch file gives me errors and I get a blank RGB image using image_view.  I have updated my question with the error output.

**Comment by [sven_007](https://answers.ros.org/users/1417/sven_007/) on 2012-02-16**:
I have the same problems as above.Have you solved them? Would you please tell me how to get it?and how to dynamic reconfigure to turn on depth_registration?Thanks very much!

**Comment by [sven_007](https://answers.ros.org/users/1417/sven_007/) on 2012-02-16**:
I have the same problems as above.Have you solved them? Would you please tell me how to get it?